# How to deal with Android dependencies

Tags: android, android-support-library

I create an new project. And the IDE automatically add android-support-v4.jar to Android Dependencies, just as the following figure. But now, I need to import a v13 class. How can I change android-support-v4.jar to android-support-v13.jar in the Android Dependencies.

[image]

Comment: Are you get solution?

Comment: not yet~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: i successed change of  android-support-v13.jar instead of android-support-v4.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Download `android-support-v13.jar` from [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/android-support/android-support-v13.jar.zip) link. Copy the jar file to `libs` folder and delete `android-support-v4.jar` from the same. Finally, from the libraries tab in java-build-path add `android-support-v13.jar` from `libs` folder

Comment: @FihopZz Right click on your project-->open properties-->click on Java build path-->there u will get 4 tabs, soyrce, project, libraries, order and export. Go to libraries tab

Answer (score 0):

you try remove `android-support-v4.jar` from libs folder and add `android-support-v13.jar` in libs folder.

Comment: Android Dependencies this folder auto generate by you do add jar file in libs folder.

Comment: you have not any jar file in libs folder so Android Dependencies not auto create in project and you have jar file in libs folder so auto generate Android Dependencies in project.

Comment: I have added v13 in he lib folder. But the IDE keeps trying ti add v4 and gives me error that cann't find v4(I've deleted it).

Comment: Java build path-> in select android-support-v4.jar and choice remove and after remove this jar from libs folder.